# How to krep auto-increment value after OPTIMZE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have an InnoDB table in which i frequently insert and delete rows.

I noticed that after I execute a delete statement on the last few rows and run optimize table the auto-increment drops back to max(id)+1

Consider the following sequence of events

Table: requests

```
Auto Increment is: 150, INSERT ROW (id 150)
Auto Increment is: 151, INSERT ROW (id 151)
Auto Increment is: 152, INSERT ROW (id 152)
Auto Increment is: 154

DELETE from requests where id in (151,152)

OPTIMIZE TABLE requests

Auto increment is: 151.
```

I want to find a way to avoid this scenario.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: I have just tried and the same thing happens when I restart the mysql service instead of optimising the table

Answer (score 2):

Seems MySQL is already working on fixing this - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18274.

But meanwhile, you can manually set the auto-increment value to whatever it should be after the OPTIMIZE TABLE is complete.

By the way, is there a specific reason why would you like to keep the auto-increment value to whatever it was before the OPTIMIZE? Because I don't think the auto-increment reset should break anything unless you don't have DELETE CASCADE for your foreign keys.

Comment: the same thing happens after restarting the mysql service... I was not able to test it before, but just now I have confirmed it. I need this because I generate .pdf files for each requests that are stored independently on the file system and are named after the request id (request_$id.pdf). I will probably solve this by editing the afterDelete method on the model in the application

Comment: Right! I'd suggest changing the PDF renaming logic if it is possible to do so. The PDF names should use values that remain constant. So perhaps you can create another field in your table, say "pdf_id" and by default set it to whatever the auto-increment field is. I mean to say that when you create a new record and a new auto-increment value is generated, assign that value to "pdf_id". Use this "pdf_id" to name your PDFs. Then when you OPTIMIZE, the auto-increment field will reset but "pdf_id" will remain to whatever it was. Makes sense?